# Virtualbox TPM vs hosts TPM

Tags: virtualbox, tpm

Question: is the TPM option in virtualbox 7 an emulator?

I want my guest OS to have NO access to the hosts hardware TPM, but instead to use a "portable" TPM from vbox, so that copying the guest to another host will bring the TPM with it.

Can i somehow identify the TPM being used by a system? (Linux guest & host) How to make sure, my guest is not accessing the hardware TPM?

Comment: Yes; A VirtualBox can be made to use a virtual TPM

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the TPM in VirtualBox is an emulated device.
It has to be emulated, because the host operating system must be
kept completely isolated from the software that is installed
inside the guest virtual machine.

For more information see
[How to Enable or Disable Secure Boot and TPM Support in VirtualBox 7.0](https://www.makeuseof.com/virtualbox-7-secure-boot-tpm/),
which starts with this text:

> VirtualBox released version 7.0 in October 2022. It is the first
> hypervisor to support the emulation of TPM chips along with all the
> other system components. VirtualBox also offers a Secure Boot feature
> in EFI mode for virtual machines. The main reason behind these two
> features was Microsoft's list of elaborate system requirements for
> Windows 11.
>
> Without emulation of the TPM 2.0 chip, users couldn't install Windows
> 11 on a virtual machine. But with VirtualBox 7.0 it is possible to
> enable Secure Boot and TPM for any Windows virtual machine. This post
> will elaborate on the methods to enable or disable TPM and Secure Boot
> for any VirtualBox virtual machine.

Comment: Shocked VMWare allowed Oracle to make the claim it was the first Hypervisor to support a virtual TPM considering I could have sworn I enabled my VMWare Workstation VM early last year to use it. It does require UEFI boot, and Secure Boot, within the VM firmware to enable at least for VMWare

Comment: @Ramhound: I only think they meant "first" in the VirtualBox line, so an ulterior version won't have these features.